# Show that limit of integral equals supremum of its set

Tags: integration, limits

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, let $f(x)$ $\geq$ $0$ for $x$ $\in$ $[a,b]$ , and let $M_n := (\int_a^b f^n)^{1/n}$.

Show that $$\lim(M_n) = \sup \{ f(x) : x \in [a,b] \}$$

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this? What theorems do you know that might be applicable, and how? What have you tried, and at what point did you get "stuck" on this problem?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't add my comment to the question. I tried to use monotone convergence theorem, but seems it is quite difficult to show it is monotone increasing. Also it is a question related to integration but seems I can't apply Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to this...

Answer (score 1):

Set $M = \sup\{f(x): x\in[a,b]\}.$ Let $\varepsilon>0$ and define $S_\varepsilon =\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)\geqslant M-\varepsilon\}$. Then
\begin{align}
M_n&=\left(\int_{[a,b]} f(x)^n\ \mathsf dx\right)^{\frac1n}\\&\geqslant \left(\int_{S_\varepsilon} (M-\varepsilon)^n\ \mathsf dx\right)^{\frac1n}\\
&\geqslant (M-\varepsilon)\mu(S_\varepsilon)^{\frac1n}
\end{align}
where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, so that
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} M_n\geqslant M. $$ For the reverse inequality, if $n>m$ then
\begin{align}
\int_{[a,b]} f(x)^n\ \mathsf dx &= \int_{[a,b]} f(x)^{n-m}f(x)^m\ \mathsf dx\\
&\leqslant\int_{[a,b]}M^{n-m} f(x)^m\ \mathsf dx\\
&=M^{n-m}\int_{[a,b]} f(x)^m\ \mathsf dx
\end{align}
and hence
$$M_n \leqslant\left(M^{n-m}\int_{[a,b]} f(x)^m\ \mathsf dx\right)^{\frac1n}\leqslant M^{\frac{n-m}m}\left(\int_{[a,b]} f(x)^m\ \mathsf dx\right)^{\frac1n},  $$
so that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} M_n\leqslant M. $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However I didn't learn Lebesgue measure, is that any proof using Darboux integral only?

Comment: I don't know of any; this problem is normally phrased in terms of $L^p$ spaces.